# How do I return an entire row from a different excel sheet by looking up a value in a column?

Tags: excel, row, vlookup, lookup, index-match

I feel like I've watched a million Youtube videos and keep getting the "#VALUE!" error. What I need is to have an input cell which I would be entering the phone number for a customer, then have that number found in a spreadsheet and return the entire row for that customer in a row underneath my input. Any ideas?

Comment: @Spaghetti but does this return the information in the row to the left and right of the matched value?

Answer (score 1):

```
=XLOOKUP($G$3;$B$2:$B$5;$A$2:$C$5)
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

```
=VLOOKUP(Lookup Cell,Lookup Range,First Column,FALSE)
```

1. Lookup Cell e.g. $A$1
2. Lookup Range e.g. $A$1:$G$1
3. First Column would be COLUMN(A1)

```
=VLOOKUP($A$1,$A$1:$G$1,COLUMN(A1),FALSE)
```